# Directive input value changing when calling directive multiple times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive,

```
(function(){
    angular.module("pulldownmodule")

    .controller("pulldownCtrl",['pullDownServices','$scope',"multiselectDefaults","templates",function(pullDownServices,$scope,multiselectDefaults,templates){

        //Local variables
        _this = this;
        var dropdownData = {};
        var currentTemplate = {};
        var firstTemplate;

        //Validation function
        function validateInput(){
            console.log(_this.dropdownid);
            if (_this.dropdownid) {
                getPullDownData(_this.dropdownid,_this.filter); 
            }
            //check if the dropdown ID is present
        }

        $scope.$watch('pulldownCtrl.dropdownid',function(newVal){
            console.log(_this.dropdownid);
            if (newVal) {
                validateInput();    
            };              
        });

    }])

    .directive('pulldown', [function(){
        return {
            scope: {},
            bindToController:{
                dropdownid:"=",
                filter:"=",
                templatetype:"@"
            },
            controller:'pulldownCtrl',
            controllerAs:'pulldownCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'pulldown/html/dropDownDirective.html'
        };
    }]);
})()
```

I am calling the directive 2 times as follows

```
<div pulldown dropdownid="currentID" templatetype="template2" filter="customFilter"></div>

<div pulldown dropdownid="currentID2" templatetype="template2" filter="customFilter2"></div>
```

Passing the value of dropdownid in the controller as

```
$scope.currentID = 1;
$scope.currentID2 = 5;
```

The issue here is if i call the directive only 1 time everything works fine, but if i call it multiple times then i get the _this.dropdownid in $watch as the second directives value. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Probably i have to create a new instance using 'new'.

Directive HTML

Following is the major part of the directives HTML,

```
<select id="searchData"  kendo-multi-select="pulldown" k-options="ddoptions" k-rebind="ddoptions" k-on-change="getChangevalue('searchData')"></select>
```

i'm using the kendo multiselect

Comment: Could you please provide your directive html also? And what is `_this.dropdownid`? Where are you set value to it?

Comment: update the question and added part of the html, _this.dropdownid is the attribute that is being passed to the directive via the bindToController when calling the directive.

Comment: I prefer you to use `link` function to do your directives logic including `$watch()`. Because, do separate `scope/ controller` for your directive.

Comment: First of all you should eliminate global variable `_this`. This has a very bad smell and could be the reason for the problem (without reading the rest of your code, I admit).

Comment: @hgoebl Whoops , declared the variable as global, you are right that was the problem, the second directive was updating the global variable which was the issue. You can make this as a answer.

Comment: Seems like @Reza already answered it. But you could avoid such mistakes with a) good editors like WebStorm b) ["use strict";](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hgoebl point out `_this = this;` it is kind of global (not application level) variable though you use in a function scope.

Use `var _this = this;`

```
//after assign "_this" is not accessible here

(function(){
   //after assign "_this" is accessible here
   angular.module("pulldownmodule")
   .controller(...function(){
      _this = this; //use var _this = this;
      //...others code
   });    
}();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
angular.module("pulldownmodule",[])

.controller("pulldownCtrl",['$scope',function($scope){

    //Local variables
    _this = this;
    // Initialize your models here
    $scope.currentID = '1';
    $scope.currentID2 = '3';

    var dropdownData = {};
    var currentTemplate = {};
    var firstTemplate;

    //Validation function
    function validateInput(){
        console.log(_this.dropdownid);
        if (_this.dropdownid) {
            getPullDownData(_this.dropdownid,_this.filter); 
        }
        //check if the dropdown ID is present
    }

    $scope.$watch('currentID', function (newVal) {
        console.log($scope.currentID);
        if (newVal) {
            validateInput();    
        };              
    });

    $scope.$watch('currentID2', function (newVal) {
        console.log($scope.currentID2);
        if (newVal) {
            validateInput();
        };
    });

}])

.directive('pulldown', [function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            dropdownid:"=",
            filter:"=",
            templatetype:"@"
        },
        template: '<select ng-model="dropdownid"> <option ng-repeat="a in [1,2,3,4,5]" value="{{a}}"> {{a}} </option> </select>',
        link: function (scope,element, attr) {
            scope.$watch("dropdownid", function (newVal) {
                scope.dropdownid;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```